# How can I get my All.in.one Canon MG2520 scanner to work?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, scanner, canon

I have a Canon MG2520 All in one printer/scanner. The printer is working fine. But I can not use the scanner. What can I do? Running XUbuntu 14.04 LTS.
I am getting an error message that seems to indicate it is a driver issue. If so, how do I go about installing a driver for this scanner?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the SANE scanner frontend: `sudo apt-get install xsane`. Some Canon scanners are supported.

Alternatively, you could use Canon's own suite called *ScanGearMP*, which you can find [here](http://de.canon.ch/Support/Consumer_Products/products/Fax__Multifunctionals/InkJet/PIXMA_MG_series/PIXMA_MG2540.aspx?type=download&language=&os=Linux). The U.S. support site of Canon doesn't offer this package, but I found it on the Swiss site.
Download and install the deb file. It doesn't come with an application launcher, so you could create one yourself. Mine looks like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Canon ScanGearMP
Exec=/usr/bin/scangearmp
Icon=scanner
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=Graphics
```

Save it as `scangearmp.desktop` in `/usr/share/applications/`, if you want to enable all users of your computer to use it. If you don't have root access or are the only user, you can use `~/.local/share/applications/` instead.